# MongoDB query in php for searching records within Cost and Price range for the structure given below

Tags: php, laravel-5, mongodb-query

This is the nearest notation that I have.

I need a query to get all record within the given specific price and quantity range.

```
{    
    prices:{
    {quantity:10,cost:2},
    {quantity:5,cost:2},
    {quantity:30,cost:5}
    }
    },
    {
    prices:{quantity:10,cost:2},
    {quantity:20,cost:2},
    {quantity:30,cost:5}
    },
    {
    prices:{quantity:15,cost:2},
    {quantity:5,cost:2},
    {quantity:30,cost:5}
}
```

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: i tried a few things like "prices.cost", elemMatch etc

Comment: Please add your attempts to the post.